# sqlpackage import database excluded users

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I built an automation backup and import Azure database to the new Azure SQL server it still has all the old users and that's a breach of security. I saw SQLpackage import no option excluded user. SQLpackage publish have ExcludeObjectTypes but it's not included data. Does anyone have a script or idea to remove all users who aren't in default users?

```
$DBServer = 'ddd.database.windows.net'
$DbUser = 'admin'
$DBPassword = 'dsfdfdsf'
$Backupfilename = 'Catalog-2022-08-30.bacpac'
$DBNameimport = 'Catalog1'


###Restore file to SQL Server
#Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance tcp:$DBServer -Username $DbUser -Password "$DBPassword " -Query "Drop database [$DBNameimport]"
#Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance tcp:$DBServer -Username $DbUser -Password "$DBPassword " -Query "Create database [$DBNameimport]"
#sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish /tsn:tcp:$DBServer,1433 /tdn:$DBNameimport /tu:$DbUser /tp:"$DBPassword" /sf:$PSScriptRoot\$Backupfilename /p:Storage=File
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finished the script auto download file backup from storage to import for a new environment and delete older users from file backup to meet security:

```
$DBServer = 'dev01.database.windows.net'
$DbUser = 'admin'
$DBPassword = '12131231'
$StorageAccountName = 'adminstorage'
$StorageAccountKey = 'sdfsdfsdf'
$ContainerName = 'Catalog-backup'
$Backupfilename = 'Catalog-2022-08-23.bacpac'
$DBName = 'Catalog'

#Copy file from blob storage

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

write-output "backup file name: $Backupfilename"
Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $Backupfilename -Container $ContainerName -Destination $PSScriptRoot -Context $ctx

#Check name database
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance tcp:$DBServer -Username $DbUser -Password "$DBPassword" -Query "Drop database [$DBNameimport]"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance tcp:$DBServer -Username $DbUser -Password "$DBPassword" -Query "Create database [$DBNameimport]"

#Restore file to SQL Server
sqlpackage.exe /Action:Import /tsn:tcp:$DBServer,1433 /tdn:$DBNameimport /tu:$DbUser /tp:"$DBPassword" /sf:$PSScriptRoot\$Backupfilename /p:Storage=File

#Delete older user when finish import
$query = "
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT @Command += 'DROP USER ['+name+'];'
FROM sys.sysusers
WHERE name not in ('guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'sys','public')
  and name not like 'db%'

EXEC (@Command);
"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance tcp:$DBServer -Username $DbUser -Password "$DBPassword" -Database $DBNameimport -Query $query
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for [SqlPackage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-extract?view=sql-server-ver16) there is a property named "IgnoreUserLoginMappings" (/p:IgnoreUserLoginMappings) that you can use to exclude users. You may need to set to true the parameter "DropObjectsNotInSource" also.

Comment: I tried extract/publish before I asked on here, but those command just work for DACPAC file and that's file not consist data stored in database. In my case, need to export and import BACPAC file and I don't see any property about user

Comment: In that case, you may have to copy the database, drop the users on the database created with the copy operation, and then export that database.